# Printing Arabic text using ZPL (from iOS)

Tags: ios, utf-8, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to print to Zebra iMZ320

This one prints when saved to a file as UTF 8 encoded and send to the printer using Zebra Utilities

^XA^LRN^CI0^XZ ^XA^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.TTF^FS^XZ ^XA ^PA1,1,1,1^FS ^FO010,610^CI28^AZN,50,40^FD*Arabic: زيبرة^FS ^PQ1 ^XZ

But does not fire from iOS source code directly.

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: You need to specify the encoding in the source code. Can you share your source for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61211077/3411787 this helped me