# Swift 2 Decode base64 always return nil

Tags: swift, base64, decode

I'm trying to decode the following string from base64 without any exit. It always returns nil. I have tried to change NSDataBase64DecodingOptions to IgnoreUnknowCharanters but it doesn't work either. I also tried to remove the padding like this answer says [swift base64 decoding returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364324/swift-base64-decoding-returns-nil/36366421#36366421) but the length of my string is divisible by 4 so It doesn't works.

string

```
PY5ehymWfQKExWxPyOImGiQkxNjyuBREmOXtQdePVpuH9PFzizaO+WTuM1sLouTQPz5UO7csloC9GjOFqkq4POmlB9d3mMJGLB2pVCNs8t9EejOcjV4fRHaITkmfMfVbizCnTvHGBwLWXjLc7gwyhu2+S9qw0NXc5jw6EdEk+zuesrdwLgqws0hDqFSoVw57+CnvUmgXwtNfKP4p64mJ9inH/0xAMarCc5N4Wjz/zmlTyd2PoDFUC/iLdZ7csau7X2M=
```

option 1

```
if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters),
        let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(decodedString) // foo
    }
```

option 2

```
 if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: pnpData, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0)),
        let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(decodedString) // foo
    }
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Which bit returns nil, the data or creating the string from the data? Where did your base64 string come from?

Comment: I assume that the Base64 decoding works, but the decoded data does not represent a valid UTF-8 sequence, so that `NSString(data: decodedData ...)` fails. What result do you expect?

Comment: @MartinR It is supossed that it's a encrypted string so after decode it I have to use AES to decrypt it.

Comment: @Wain decodedData has data but decodedString is nil

Comment: Then don't convert the data to a string. AES-decrypt the *data.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt on string "PY5ehymWfQKExWxPyOImGiQkxNjyuBREmOXtQdePVpuH9PFzizaO+WTuM1sLouTQPz5UO7csloC9GjOFqkq4POmlB9d3mMJGLB2pVCNs8t9EejOcjV4fRHaITkmfMfVbizCnTvHGBwLWXjLc7gwyhu2+S9qw0NXc5jw6EdEk+zuesrdwLgqws0hDqFSoVw57+CnvUmgXwtNfKP4p64mJ9inH/0xAMarCc5N4Wjz/zmlTyd2PoDFUC/iLdZ7csau7X2M="

**This works, that string getting encode and decode too**

```
    let utf8str = "PY5ehymWfQKExWxPyOImGiQkxNjyuBREmOXtQdePVpuH9PFzizaO+WTuM1sLouTQPz5UO7csloC9GjOFqkq4POmlB9d3mMJGLB2pVCNs8t9EejOcjV4fRHaITkmfMfVbizCnTvHGBwLWXjLc7gwyhu2+S9qw0NXc5jw6EdEk+zuesrdwLgqws0hDqFSoVw57+CnvUmgXwtNfKP4p64mJ9inH/0xAMarCc5N4Wjz/zmlTyd2PoDFUC/iLdZ7csau7X2M=".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let encodedString : String = base64Encoded!
    print(encodedString) // my encoded data

    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString:  encodedString, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let decodedString : String = String(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print(decodedString) // my plain data
```

**This doesn't work, that decoded string dont get encode**

```
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString:  "PY5ehymWfQKExWxPyOImGiQkxNjyuBREmOXtQdePVpuH9PFzizaO+WTuM1sLouTQPz5UO7csloC9GjOFqkq4POmlB9d3mMJGLB2pVCNs8t9EejOcjV4fRHaITkmfMfVbizCnTvHGBwLWXjLc7gwyhu2+S9qw0NXc5jw6EdEk+zuesrdwLgqws0hDqFSoVw57+CnvUmgXwtNfKP4p64mJ9inH/0xAMarCc5N4Wjz/zmlTyd2PoDFUC/iLdZ7csau7X2M=", options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let decodedString : String = String(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print(decodedString) // my plain data
```

**This could be reason, check on https://www.base64decode.org/**

[image]

**Though special characters can't be hold in String.**

Comment: It is suposed that it is an encrypted string

Comment: That string is not encrypted, when we decrypt on https://www.base64decode.org/ , it should give meaning full message, but it is purely giving exceptional characters.  i doubt on encrypt code. Please make sure once.

Comment: I receive this string from a external API. You need a key to decrypt it in AES but anyway I will contact to them...no way to decode it.

Comment: Ohh, i guess you were doing encryption for same. No way to decode it or they have to give a key or logic to decode this string. You can accept answer if helped.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is trying to Solve this issue moving from Java to Swift.

This Answer helped me out, you might need to append("==")

[Swift 3 base64 decode return nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397136/swift-3-base64-decode-return-nil)

You might need to append("==")

Comment: Its really helpful

Comment: Man! this answer saved my life

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can follow this

https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#data-padding

and use following method to decode(i guess your string is encoded by aes cbc and base64, if you want to decode this string, you must know the encode key and iv)

```
"PY5ehymWfQKExWxPyOImGiQkxNjyuBREmOXtQdePVpuH9PFzizaO+WTuM1sLouTQPz5UO7csloC9GjOFqkq4POmlB9d3mMJGLB2pVCNs8t9EejOcjV4fRHaITkmfMfVbizCnTvHGBwLWXjLc7gwyhu2+S9qw0NXc5jw6EdEk+zuesrdwLgqws0hDqFSoVw57+CnvUmgXwtNfKP4p64mJ9inH/0xAMarCc5N4Wjz/zmlTyd2PoDFUC/iLdZ7csau7X2M=".decryptBase64ToString(cipher)
```